# Cucumber's support/hooks.rb equivalent in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I need to write timestamps to a log file before each rspec test. With cucumber this can be acomplished easily by using hooks.rb. Is there an equivalent way to do this with Rspec? Mind you that this has to be done in a centralized manner. It's not practical for me to place code before each rspec file because my test suite is quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out myself.

In the **spec_helper.rb** file, within a

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
...
end
```

block place the following code:

```
config.before(:each) do
  puts 'this line will be executed before each test'
end
```